# Why does my IDE mark this variable as unused?

Tags: php, phpstorm

```
$freeSlots = 0; //Unused local variable 'freeSlots'. The value of the variable is overwritten immediately.

if (strtotime($endDate) === strtotime($startDate))
{
    return $endSlot - $startSlot;
}
else
{
    $freeSlots = (5 - $startSlot) + ($endSlot - 1);
    $newTime = strtotime('+1 day', $newTime);

    if (date("Y-m-d", $newTime) === $endDate)
    {
        return $freeSlots;
    }

    do
    {
        if (!(date('N', $newTime) >= 6))
        {
            $freeSlots += 4;
        }
        $newTime = strtotime('+1 day', $newTime);
    } while (date("Y-m-d", $newTime) !== $endDate);
}

return $freeSlots; //but is clearly used here
```

Why does my PhpStrom say the variable is unsed?

**EDIT:**

My main problem is, that just using it in else isn't enough because that's a different scope. the return is outside of the else.

Comment: May because you are declaring it again inside the `else` condition?

Comment: Is this a part of a `function`?

Comment: Because it's never used since the line you've left comment on. Either `return` happens in `if` block, or the value is re-defined in `else` block. Both cases => no use of initial value

Comment: @CaioKawasaki he's not "declaring" it, he's "assigning" to it.  Unfortunately PHP doesn't separate the two :(

Comment: As a side note: The first `if` has a return statement.. why do you have thye `else`? you can put everything in the `else` just after the `if` and it will do the same

Comment: No error here. IDE is correct.

Comment: @LazyOne uhm yes.. it's just a warning. still annoys me.

Comment: could the downvotes tell me whats so bad about this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you don't need the line

```
$freeSlots = 0; //Unused local variable 'freeSlots'. The value of the variable is overwritten immediately.
```

As the IDE tells this variable will be overwritten immediately by this line:

```
$freeSlots = (5 - $startSlot) + ($endSlot - 1);
```

So the first line is in fact a line that is completely unnecessary and can be deleted. You never use $freeSlots, you're redefining it.

To clarify the scope:

```
$freeSlots = 0; //Unused local variable 'freeSlots'. The value of the variable is overwritten immediately.

if (strtotime($endDate) === strtotime($startDate))
{
    return $endSlot - $startSlot;
}

$freeSlots = (5 - $startSlot) + ($endSlot - 1);
$newTime = strtotime('+1 day', $newTime);

if (date("Y-m-d", $newTime) === $endDate)
{
    return $freeSlots;
}

do
{
    if (!(date('N', $newTime) >= 6))
    {
        $freeSlots += 4;
    }
    $newTime = strtotime('+1 day', $newTime);
} while (date("Y-m-d", $newTime) !== $endDate);

return $freeSlots; //but is clearly used here
```

The code above does the EXACT same as your code does. You don't need to use the `else`. If the condition is true, you're returining a value. Else you continue on. No need for the else. And so it's the same scope.

Comment: but that's a different scope isn't it?

Comment: control structures share the same scope

Comment: @PhilippSander no, it's the same scope. Either it won't be used because you're returning something other or you're setting a new value to $freeSlots, but the firstly defined value of `0` isn't USED anywhere. It just will be overwritten.

Comment: Phpstorm ist really great in figuring out stuff like that ;)